# Removing an item from a CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

i'm pretty new to C# but have 3 years of java from University and was just wondering about a question when it comes to removing objects from GUIs.

I have a CheckedListBox that gets items added to it when the user wants to add an order. The reason for the CheckedListBox is to be able to remove the items.

my "add to order" button:

```
 private void add_to_order_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Food food in GlobalVariables.m_foodMenu)
            {
                if (food_combo.Text.Equals(food.name))
                {
                    GlobalVariables.m_currentFood.Add(food);
                    current_order_box.Items.Add(food.name +" "+ food.food_price +" "+ food.food_size);

                }
            }

        }
```

My main issue is that it is displayed as "Pizza 10 SMALL" but I cant remove the item using a String type of comparisson incase there is also another object with the same details. For example they want 2x pizza 10 small - it would show up as

"pizza 10 small"
"pizza 10 small" 
so if I do a string comparison the wrong one may get removed.
Is there a way to somehow link the object to the item? The reason being is I have a List that will be used at Checkout to calculate the total etc..

Comment: The best way is to add not strings but real objects. Declare a class, maybe `FoodItem` with a nice `ToString()` method and add instances of that class. Now the comparisons will work and you can also add more helpful functions to the class as needed..

Comment: You haven't tagged this with the type of project you're working on; Windows Forms? ASP.NET? WPF? The answer changes based on which of those you're using. Also, you probably want to look at the [Microsoft Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx)

Comment: @TiesonT. Hi, yeah sorry my bad. I've been up 24 hours with my final uni deadline so some things are slipping my mind. For Naming guidelines, my University Tutor has his own that we were taught to [use](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8681/54e591ee1c316c16b18cd6617915fae90b79.pdf)

Comment: So, which is it? WinForms and WebForms are two different technologies.

Comment: @TiesonT. Winform